# How to perform synthetic division with a quadratic divisor?

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have to perform the following operation:

$$\frac{5x^4 + 5x^3 - 3x^2 - 3x - 2}{2x^2 + 5x + 3}$$

Using synthetic division.

Despite watching many tutorials, I don't quite understand the process and how it's supposed to work for quadratic divisors in this case.

I was wondering if this process could be clarified for me using this as an example.

Comment: It would make work easier for people wanting to help you if, instead of asking for a detailed discussion of your example without telling us where you are stuck, you tell which step(s) you don't understand in [that already detailed one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#For_non-monic_divisors), for instance.

Comment: It's just long division. You multiply the denominator by something, then subtract that from the numerator. Repeat until the numerator is lower order than the denominator. Here you'll start by multiplying $2x^2+5x+3$ by $\frac52 x^2$ then subtract.